# how to display jupyterlab startup output

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-lab

In jupyter, you can put python files in a certain folder that get executed between starting the kernel and handing execution over to the user. If something goes wrong in these startup scripts, jupyter (specifically jupyterlab, but I doubt it'll be specific to that) swallows the errors and just hands execution over to the user. We're looking for a way to either

- configure jupyter to show all the output from the startup script (not just errors, e.g. an motd would be nice too)
- set some variable so jupyter displays a banner with some text from the scripts in the folder

Workarounds that we've found that weren't good enough:

1. Running ipython from the console does not swallow these errors, but you can only look at the logs after you know something is wrong. We need to be actively notified in advance
2. Having the last line of the startup scripts be something like startup_ok = True and telling everyone to check startup_ok first is still too much effort to force on all our users.

example setup in our jupyterlab, note that the error is completely invisible and you can only notice it by checking the token manually or checking ipython (blocked out sensitive info)

[image: example]

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal example to help us understand what exactly gets swallowed?

Comment: @krassowski added an image, but there's not much to show, only that it doesn't get shown :/ hope this helps

Comment: What version of JupyterLab are you using? I think that kernel errors should be transmitted to console in JupyterLab 3 (with recent jupyter server and ipykernel), but I am not sure...

Comment: By console I mean log console - an extra blue icon appearing on the status bar (the status bar is not visible on your screenshot), not the code console.

Comment: Interesting, I haven't seen that but we are indeed running an older version of jupyter at the moment I believe (we're looking at upgrading soon though, so that might help a bit already). Can you show an image of what that would look like?

Answer (score 2):

If you care about ipython startup scripts reliably finishing, **I suggest not using them at all - use ipython extensions.**

You can change your ipython profile's ipython_config.py to raise if extensions fail, and to load your extension

```
c.InteractiveShellApp.reraise_ipython_extension_failures = True
c.InteractiveShellApp.extensions.append(
  'your_extension_example'
)
```

`your_extension_example` is the package where you put your startup code in.

If you don't want to put your startup code in a package, you can change the path and just load it as a regular file, e.g. in same file at the top

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "startup_extensions"))
```

I use this setup quite often so I've created a repo for an easier start https://github.com/modelpredict/reliable-ipython-startup - you just clone the repo and run one cp command to create a placeholder for your startup code.

If you are interested in more details, you can find them at https://modelpredict.com/how-to-write-reliable-scripts-ipython/.

Comment: Interesting way of tackling this. What happens if an extension fails? Where can you see this output then? It seems like the entire IPython would fail then, would this be blocking if it's something non-essential like an optional package that a user wants auto-imported?

Comment: + heads up, in your section 2 of your writeup, you've got a typo: "profile_defauly"

Comment: Thanks for the typo detected.

**Would IPython fail then?**

Correct. IPython won't start, and you'll see the error where you start ipython. If it's in the CLI, you'll see it in the console. If it's Jupyter Kernel, I believe (have to double check) Jupyter will tell you that it failed, and you'll have to go and see in logs.

Comment: >  "would this be blocking if it's something non-essential like an optional package that a user wants auto-imported?"

It would. I may need to clarify that in the writeup.
- put things that you want to run reliably in extensions
- the rest can go in startup scripts if you can tolerate "silently fail and continue" behaviour